# How to manipulate an instance of a mutable struct in Rust - ownership woes

Tags: rust

I'm just learning Rust, coming from years of C++, and I'm having some difficulty understanding how to deal with some of the ownership restrictions. Specifically, in this little program, which is just a training exercise, I get two different error messages.

`let stat = Stdev::new();`

The above statement gets the message:  move occurs because `stat` has type `Stdev`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

```
    stat.add(x);
```

The above statement gets the message: `stat` moved due to this method call, in previous iteration of loop.

Here's the whole program:

```
struct Stdev
{
    count : u32,
    sum : f64,
    sq_sum : f64
}

impl Stdev
{
    fn new() -> Self
    {
        Stdev{count:0, sum:0.0, sq_sum:0.0}
    }

    fn add(mut self, x : f64)
    {
        self.count += 1;
        self.sum += x;
        self.sq_sum += x * x;
    }
    
    fn stdev(&self) -> f64
    {
        if self.count == 0 { return 0.0; }
        let n = self.count as f64;
        let mean = self.sum / n;
        let variance = self.sq_sum / n - mean * mean;
        variance.sqrt()
    }
}

use rand::Rng;

fn main() {
    let count = 1000;
    let stat = Stdev::new();
    for _ in 1..count
    {
        let x = rng.gen_range(0.0..100.0);
        stat.add(x);
    }
    
    println!("Standard deviation is {}", stat.stdev());
}
```

So, two questions:
1: How can I initialize the variable `stat` with an instance of the `Stdev` struct?
2: How can I modify fields within the struct via a method call without running into ownership problems?

Just as a reference, here is essentially the same logic, in C++ instead of Rust, and this program works just fine. In the following code, the class `accum` is the equivalent of the Rust struct `Stdev`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

class accum
{
    int count;
    double sum;
    double sq_sum;
    
public:
    accum();
    int add(double);
    double stdev();
};

accum::accum()
{
    count = 0;
    sum = 0.0;
    sq_sum = 0.0;
}

int accum::add(double x)
{
    sum += x;
    sq_sum += x * x;
    return ++count;
}

double accum::stdev()
{
    if (0 == count) return 0;
    double mean = sum / count;
    double variance = sq_sum / count - mean * mean;
    return sqrt(variance);
}

double gen_range()
{
    double x = rand();
    x /= RAND_MAX;
    return x * 100.0;
}

int main()
{
    int count = 100;
    accum stat;
    for(int i = 0; count > i; ++i)
    {
        double x = gen_range();
        stat.add(x);
    }
    
    std::cout << "Standard deviation is " << stat.stdev() << "\n";
}
```

I'm particularly confused about the second error. If `stat` was moved, where was it moved to? There was no assignment, just a method call. I'm confused. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `add` function to take a mutable reference to `self` instead of moving it:

```rust
fn add(&mut self, x: f64)
```

Using the current declaration, calling `add` will actually move `stat` and pass the ownership to the `add` method. Hence, `stat` can not be used after that call, but the loop needs it, this is why you get the error.

Your `new` method is fine.

Comment: Thanks :) Your suggestion, plus adding `mut` to the declaration of `stat`, fixed the problem. It's all good now.